# What code can echo a character in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

The following code does assemble, build and run successfully but it doesn't do anything so I want it to output a character that's entered from the keyboard and display it to the screen. How can I do this? I've tried different lines of code and looked online but I can't find anything.

I'm still learning asm so any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
        ;NASM-IDE ASM Assistant Assembler Project File
;BITS 16            ;Set code generation to 16 bit mode
;ORG 0x0100     ;Set code start address to 0100h


SEGMENT .text        ;Main code segment

PUTCH:             
PUSH AX        

MOV AH, 2H
INT 21H

POP AX                 

ret  

GETCH:
PUSH BX

MOV BH, AH 

MOV AH, 08H 
INT 21H    

MOV AH, BH 

POP BX

ret

PUTLINE:
PUSH AX
PUSH BX

MOV AH, 004CH
INT 21H   

POP AX
POP BX

ret

SEGMENT .data       ;Initialised data segment


SEGMENT .bss        ;Uninitialised data segment
```

Comment: `int 21h` is a real-mode DOS call. Are you running under that environment?

Comment: Yes. I'm using DOSBOX with nasmide, if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only have 3 procedures: putch, getch and putline. But there is no "main" procedure. That's why you don't see any output.

If you add the following code at the beginning (before "PUTCH:"), you may get it to read a character from keyboard, then echo it to the STDOUT, and then terminates the program.

```
XOR AX,AX           ; clear AX
call GETCH          ; read a char into AL
call PUTCH          ; print the char from AL
MOV AX, 4C00h       
INT 21h             ; exit with code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, DX. I don't know what STDOUT is but I used the code and it doesn't anything different from before. I can press any character but it tells me to press another to continue. When I do, nothing is output and the program returns to the previous screen. Do I need to use another register and move it or maybe call putline?

Comment: STDOUT means console/screen. From your description, it looks like you are running the program from an IDE. When the program terminates, it asks you to press another key to return to the IDE. One thing to try is to do "call GETCH; call PUTCH" two times. If the program reads two keys before asking to return to IDE, then you know it is executing properly. Then, you can debug the return value (AL) from GETCH to find out whether the problem is with GETCH or PUTCH.

Comment: I had a play around and managed to do it. I had to call GETCH, move AL into DL and call all 3 subroutines (PUTCH, PUTLINE, GETCH) before moving the register again and calling PUTCH again before exiting. There might be some redundant code in there but it works. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I cant vote for your answer as I don't have any rep points left, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

mov ah,01

int 21h

;this service accepts a character, echoes it, and stores it into al